# Recurrent events and Outlook export

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a calendar on my website and i need to add recurrent events and outlook export.

What is the best way to handle recurrent events? (mssql + C#)

How can I export multiple events to outlook 2003?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the easiest way I can think of would be to use an embedded Google Calendar, which already supports embedded events and export to outlook.

As far as the "best way" to implement it, it'd probably be best to follow the [iCalendar Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445) as it is supported by many applications, including Outlook.  Hopefully looking over that will give you a better idea of how to implement it if you so wish, but I highly believe that if there's a free extensible solution out there already, it's best to use that and program extensions for it to suit your needs.